# django ORM query for three models

Tags: django, postgresql

i have three models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Transaction(models.Model):
    debited_customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, blank=True)
    credited_customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, blank=True)
    amount_equ = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Account(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

All table names are 'pr_' + lowercase model name. Some customers don't have account. I want to sum 'amount_equ' from all transactions, where either debited_customer or a credited_customer is a customer with account. i can achieve this with a raw sql query:

```
SELECT SUM(tt.amount_equ)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.id, amount_equ
    FROM pr_transaction t INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT c.id
        FROM pr_customer c INNER JOIN pr_account a ON c.id=a.customer_id) cc
    ON t.debited_customer_id=cc.id OR t.credited_customer_id=cc.id) tt
```

Is it possible to do the same without raw sql? and how?
I tried

```
Transaction.objects.filter(Q(credited_customer__account__isnull = False) | Q(debited_customer__account__isnull = False)).values('id').distinct()
```

and it seems to give correct set of transactions, but I don't know how to get the sum, I tried `.aggregate(Sum('amount_equ'))` but in this case it takes distinct 'amount_equ' instead of distinct pk and the result becomes wrong

Comment: Why don't you allow negative numbers in the Transaction model? Depending on the sign (+ or -) you can know whether it was a debit or credit. That way, summing up the totals per customer is trivial.

Comment: you don't understand the question. it is not important in my project, whether amount is debit or credit, and i don't need sum per customer. I need total sum of transactions, where at least one customer has an account. anyway, imagine i have sign (+ or -) in transaction and please provide a code